# Lineage is not visible for Hive Managed Table in HDP Atlas

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-atlas

I am using Atlas with HDP for creating the lineage flow for my hive tables but the lineage is only visible for the Hive External tables. I have created hive managed tables and perform a join operation to create a new table and imported the hive meta store using `import-hive.sh` placed under hook-bin folder. But the lineage for the managed table is not visible.

Even the HDFS directory is not listed for the managed table. But, if I check for the external table HDFS directory is available.

Can anyone help me over here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two factors which were causing the issue in my case, first was with the Hive-Hook and second was with `offsets.topic.replication.factor`. To resolve this below steps were implemented:-

**1) Re-install Hive Hook for the atlas**
  Grep the lists of the services installed for *Apache Atlas* and *re-install the Hive-Hook* jar

**2) Kafka offset replication property**
   Changes the `offsets.topic.replication.factor` value to 1.

By implementing the above changes, lineage is reflecting in the Atlas itself for Hive as well as sqoop.